# Adding controls to a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button quote = new Button();
    Button reply = new Button();
    Button edit = new Button();
    Label UsersMessage = new Label();
    UsersMessage.Text = "Users Message: question was submitted";


    Table tabl = new Table();
    TableRow tablRow=new TableRow();
    TableCell tablCell=new TableCell();



    tablCell.Controls.Add(quote);
    tablCell.Controls.Add(reply);
    tablCell.Controls.Add(edit);
    tablCell.Controls.Add(UsersMessage);

    tablRow.Cells.Add(tablCell);
    tabl.Rows.Add(tablRow);
}
```

I am trying to add a table with a row, cell with buttons and a label in it. Why nothing is added, when I launch the page? (There is nothing added in the source code, when I view it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to add the `Table` control itself to the page's form:

```
Page.Form.Controls.Add(tabl);
```

Comment: Control 'ctl02' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. - gives me an exception

Comment: @Dmitry, true, since there are buttons in your table, it should be added to the page's form and not to the page itself. Answer updated, sorry for the blunder.

Comment: Thanks, your answer solved the problem. any idea on how i can control the location of all the items that i added inside the table cell. i want the buttons to appear at the bottom of the cell and the label at the top of the cell

Comment: @Dmitry, I would add the label first, then either style it with `display: block;` or add a `<br />` element after it, then add the buttons.

Comment: i got it. so i need to simply to apply some css/html to make it look right.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

you do not add the controls to the page itself ;)

```
controlContainer.Controls.Add(tabl);
```

would do the trick

where `controlContainer` is a control you've created on the ASPX like a `asp:placeholder` or `asp:panel`. In this way you can define the location where the controls must appear in a specific manner.

**important note:** however when you add controls in this way, you will enter a worrisome area. If you are intending to use the buttons for `postback` this approach will not work quite as shown above. Please mind/google/bing terms as asp.net `page-lifecycle`, `viewstate`, `eventwire` `control-id's` etc... **[a nice tutorial is here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx#postadlink)**

Comment: an exception was thrown when i added the controls...Control 'ctl02' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Comment: of course: you must add the runat=server attribute to your controlscontainer tag so: `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="controlContainer" />`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add the table to the page controls collection.

```
this.Controls.Add(tabl);
```

Or, if you have a specific control you want to add the table to, use that.